# MongoDB best way to store values for Query and Return

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dictionary

I want to store data in subgroups and I'm not sure what's the best way to store that data and what's the best way to query it.
I'm storing tasks for let's say any user or project.
I initially thought to store a unique ID for every task to make it easier to query it later on. My solution would look like this.

```
"tasks": {
    "task01: {"assigned": "Tom"...},
    "task02: {"assigned": "Ben"...},
    ....
```

But after reading my way through the docs it seems like it's a more common way to store data in arrays like this.

```
"tasks": {[
    {"assigned": "Tom"...},
    {"assigned": "Ben"...},
    ....
```

What is your experienced opinion about this? Which way should be the most professional way to build the data structure?
I would love to be able to version up the tasks later on and have relations. As multiple users can have multiple tasks.

On the second side, I'm having problems filtering the queried result to the sub-object of the array. Which I explained with samples below.

I know there are a lot of threads on this topic. Also, I read my way through the Query Documentation [Query Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) and [Project fields to return](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)
I'm still not sure when I should use which or if one of these methods is totally wrong when working with MongoDB.

## Simplified sample data:

```
# Add object to array
collection_usr.update_one({"name": "Sample Name"}, {"$addToSet": {"tasks": [
{
    "fx": True,
    "time": 15,
    "version": 1,
    "assigned": "Tom"
},
{
    "fx": False,
    "time": 20,
    "version": 1,
    "assigned": "Ben"
},
{
    "fx": True,
    "time": 5,
    "version": 1,
    "assigned": "James"
},
{
    "fx": FALSE,
    "time": 10,
    "version": 2,
    "assigned": "James"
},
]}})
```

## What I've tried:

```
# Find array
for x in collection_usr.find({"tasks.assigned": "Ben"}, {"tasks.fx": 1, "tasks.time": 1}):
    pprint(x)
```

## The filtered result I'm looking for:

```
{
    "fx": False,
    "time": 20,
    "version": 1,
    "assigned": "Ben"
}
```

Comment: Did you try the [$ (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html)?

Comment: @parsad_ thank you for your tip. That definitely starts to help to answer the filter question. But please consider a full answer for the data structure as well. So I could accept it as a solution.

Comment: Here is an example of what you are trying to store and query: [Working with Arrays in MongoDB](https://www.codementor.io/@prasadsaya/working-with-arrays-in-mongodb-16s303gkd3). It has little more details.